# CURLOPT_RESOLVE option doesn't work properly with curl php function

Tags: php, curl, localization

I'm trying to execute a curl request using `CURLOPT_RESOLVE` but I get an error :

> Warning: curl_setopt() [function.curl-setopt]: Invalid curl
>   configuration option

This following line set the option :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RESOLVE, 'example.com:443:127.0.0.1');
```

Any idea what's wrong ?

Comment: I think you have to add the url's protocol "http or https"

Comment: Take a look at my article here: https://www.codementor.io/oluwaseye/curl-get-using-codeigniter-du107solo Though it is for Codeigniter framework, it might be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

From the php.net doc:

> An array of hostname, port, and IP address strings, each element separated by a colon. In the format: array("example.com:80:127.0.0.1")

So you can do that:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RESOLVE, ['example.com:443:127.0.0.1']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RESOLVE, 'http://example.com:443:127.0.0.1');
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no such option `CURLOPT_RESOLVE` available which is leading this warning. Please see the list of options on php.net site [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

Comment: The curl_errno() method returns no error... But the error (from this specific service) is that I have to be in the same country (France). I run my code in localhost but it seems I'm not in the same country. And the curl request works in command line (mac os X)...